# Output minified javascript file to a different directory with YUI Compressor File Watcher in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, minify, yui-compressor, file-watcher

I'm using YUI Compressor JS as my file watcher in intellij to minify my javascript files. The compressor works fine when i set 'Arguments' and 'Output path to refresh' parameters like below:

```
Arguments = $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js   
Output path to refresh = $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js
```

It then produces the minified file in the original file's folder. What I can not achieve here is that I want minified files to be placed in some other directory.
So far I tried to set the two aforementioned parameters with values below:

```
Arguments= $FileName$ -o $FileParentDir$-min\$FileDirName$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js   
Output paths to refresh = $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js
```

But it then generates the minified version of the javascript file and overwrites it to the original file; prompting me with 'File Cache Conflict' dialoge like below.
[File Cache Conflict Dialoge Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqmhi.jpg)
My original javascript files reside in `'webapp/resources/js'` folder, but I want minified files to be generated in `'webapp/resources/js-min'` folder with the same structure as in `'webapp/resources/js'` folder.

Answer (score 1):

n the Arguments text box, type:
$FileName -o /**your_custom_directory**/
the Arguments pass to compresssor and it put your out put file in your_custom_directory then in "out put path to refresh" insert your_custom_directory too,this pass to phpstorm for indexing file

for me its like this

js>my_js_file
js>min>result

Arguments: $FileName$ -o $FileDir$/min/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js
output paths to refresh:/min

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $FileParentDir$/js-min/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js?

Comment: no, it won't preserve the structure inside the target dir;`-o $ProjectFileDir$/webapp/resources/js-min/$FileDirPathFromParent(js)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.js` is better, but won't work on Windows anyway

Comment: @Oksana I've tried a bunch of path patterns with macros like this and others, but unfortunately non of them worked. 
As I said in the comment section in lena's answer above, the problem arises when you have a path that has a ":" in it. Only relative paths would work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows? YUI Compressor doesn't seem to accept Windows absolute path as a `-o` value... When I run `java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -v -o C:\WebstormProjects\untitled3\webapp\resources\js-min\sub\subsub\f3.min.js f3.js`, no `f3.min.js` is produced, the original file is modified instead:(
As far as I can see from the last comment in https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/78 thread, the bug should be fixed in yuicompressor-2.4.9. But this version is not available at https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/releases, and the link to jar provided in comment seems to be outdated...
In general, I'd strongly recommend using a different JS minifier, as **YUI Compressor** looks dead - no updates since 2013

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows. I guess you're right, whatever path I try with macros, has a problem, and that's because of inherent **YUI Compressor**'s problem with paths that have ":" in them.
Surprisingly, there has been also a commit on the project code base in github for this issue, but it seems that it's not bundled in any version.
[link](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/commit/350933e2ef1651b3631ea4b1898b8e40f9f18aaf)

Comment: What other JS minifier you would suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest [UglifyJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js); [Closure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/closure) can also be considered